# java thread synchronization : i get "undefined value"

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

The following bloc of android code tries to get a return value from a javascript function, and then assign it to a class variable, and after i use this class variable when instantiating another class;

This is my code :

```
      //class variables
                String innerElementNum = "0";
                private final Object lock = new Object();
                MyAdapter myAdapter;

            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:inner()");
                    while (responseFromJS.equals(""))
                        lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                (!responseFromJS.equals("empty"))
                    innerElementNum = responseFromJS;
                }
                responseFromJS = "";
            }

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(EditorActivity.this);
```

And in MyAdapter class, i use the variable "innerElementNum", like that :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

       Context context;

       int itemsNum = Integer.parseInt(innerElementNum); 
       String[] itemsArray = new String[itemsNum];


       MyAdapter(Context c){
           context = c;
           if (itemsNum > 0) {
           for (int i=0 ; i<itemsNum ; i++) {
               int j = i+1; 
               itemsArray[i] = j+"";
           }
           }
       }
       ....... etc
}
```

My problem is the synchronization : when instantiating MyAdapter class, "innerElementNum" variable have "undefined" value, i mean, when I instantiate the class, the variable has not yet had the right value.

any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well "undefined" is Javascript specific.  You are almost certainly parsing a json that looks like

```
{
   elementNum: "undefined"
}
```

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with concurrency.

When you say

> "undefined" value, i mean, when I instantiate the class, the variable
>   has not yet had the right value.

`String num = "undefined"` is technically assigned in Java.  I would think you need to fix that Javascript that is building this json.

**Also as a side note:**

You shouldn't be testing String equivalence by the `==` operator.  This tests reference equivalence and not content.  You should use `.equals`

Comment: no, my javascript is ok, because when i debug step by step , i got the right value from javascript but when i assign this value to the class variable "innerElementNum", and then use it in another bloc of code, his value is undefined

Comment: But when you parse the String the value of the string is "undefined" and you get a parse fail exception saying you cannot parse the string "undefined"?

Comment: no, when i debug step by step and arrive to this line "myAdapter = new MyAdapter(EditorActivity.this);" and then i check the value of the variable "responseFromJS" it contains "3" and i check the variable "innerElementNum" it contains "undefined", after this checking i continue and the program crash in this line "int itemsNum = Integer.parseInt(innerElementNum);" and give this error "unable to parse 'undefined' as integer" because in this line of my code, i'm trying to parse an "undefined" value to integer.

Comment: When you say an undefined value you actually are saying a String with the value of "undefined" there is no such state of a field or variable in Java as undefined.  For whatever reason innerElementNum is being assigned as `innerElementNum = new String("undefined");` or the more readable `innerElementNum = "undefined";`  No one here will be able to tell you why it is being assigned the string value of "undefined"

Comment: When debugging step over `(!responseFromJS.equals("empty"))       innerElementNum = responseFromJS;    }` and if innerElementNum still does not equal an integer which you are sure it should be then you have to see why `responseFromJS` is the value `new String("undefined")`

Comment: sorry if i couldn't be able to explain well! and i don't understand "why responseFromJS is the value new String("undefined")", i told you that responseFromJS got value "3" (from js) and i can see this value when debugging (if i select the variable and i click right, and Watch in eclipse) i can see the value of the variables in the run time, and when i do the same thing to Watch  innerElementNum value, i find that his value is undefined

Comment: I just don't believe that you are seeing the value from responseFromJS to not be "undefined" at some point.  Unless `innerElementNum` is assigned to at some other point or another time, the value of `responseFromJS` at some point is the string value "undefined".  Again I don't know if you are confusing what it means to have the value of undefined.  In Javascript the value/state of undefined for a field is very specific with the language itself and has no bearing in Java otherwise.

Comment: Try this.  Each time you assign to responseFromJS print out the value. `responseFromJS = ...;  System.out.println(responseFromJS);  `